# Insert a record in Table while Editing a record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I'm using ASP.NET MVC5. and I have create two Tables first one is ticket and the other one is AuditTrails. Two Tables have the same columns but AuditTrails have one more coloumns which is Date to save the current date each time tickets is updated.

the purpose of having these two tables is to track the changes made in DB.

I need to edit the Edit Controller to add a new record in AuditTrails Table While Editing the Tickets table.

below listed what I did in the Edit POST Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ITSEdit([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Badge,Phone,Email,Department,Location,Issue_Category,Description,CREATION_DATETIME,CREATED_BY,CLOSED_DATETIME,CLOSED_BY,LAST_UPDATE_DATETIME,LAST_UPDATE_BY,STATUS,ASSIGNED_TO,NOTE,Busenise_Type,Date")] Ticket ticket)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (ticket.STATUS == "Closed")
            {
                ticket.CLOSED_DATETIME = DateTime.Now;
                ticket.CLOSED_BY = User.Identity.Name;

            }
            else
            {
                ticket.LAST_UPDATE_BY = User.Identity.Name;
                ticket.LAST_UPDATE_DATETIME = DateTime.Now;
            }

            db.Entry(ticket).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            try { 
            var audit = new AuditTrail();
            audit.ID = ticket.ID;
            audit.Name = ticket.Name;
            audit.STATUS = ticket.STATUS;
            audit.Phone = ticket.Phone;
            audit.NOTE = ticket.NOTE;
            audit.Location = ticket.Location;
            audit.LAST_UPDATE_DATETIME = ticket.LAST_UPDATE_DATETIME;
            audit.LAST_UPDATE_BY = ticket.LAST_UPDATE_BY;
            audit.Issue_Category = ticket.Issue_Category;
            audit.Email = ticket.Email;
            audit.Description = ticket.Description;
            audit.Department = ticket.Department;
            audit.CREATION_DATETIME = ticket.CREATION_DATETIME;
            audit.CREATED_BY = ticket.CREATED_BY;
            audit.CLOSED_DATETIME = ticket.CLOSED_DATETIME;
            audit.Busenise_Type = ticket.Busenise_Type;
            audit.Badge = ticket.Badge;
            audit.ASSIGNED_TO = ticket.ASSIGNED_TO;
            audit.Date = DateTime.Now;
            //db.Entry(audit).State = EntityState.Added;
            //db.SaveChanges();
            db.AuditTrails.Add(audit);
            db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {

            }
            return RedirectToAction("ITSDetails", new { id = ticket.ID });

        }
        return View(ticket);
    }
```

Each time I Have got error in `db.SaveChanges();`

this is the error that I got

> Invalid object name 'dbo.AuditTrails'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object
>   name 'dbo.AuditTrails'.

can anyone help me.
thanks in Advance,

Comment: _"Each time I have got error"_. What error?

Comment: @StephenMuecke please see the update thank you:)

Comment: That suggests a table named `AuditTrails` does not exist

Comment: but it's exisit         public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<KSAU_HS.Models.AuditTrail> AuditTrails { get; set; }

Comment: Check the ```database```. Is the table ```dbo.AuditTrail``` there?

Comment: yes I have the table is there,